# Cómo darle estilo al FileType de un formulario

Tags: php, html, twig, symfony5

Necesito darle estilo al FileType, utilizando Bootstrap, pero cada cambio que le realizo afecta en conjunto al botón de seleccionar archivo y donde sale el nombre del archivo seleccionado.

ArchivoController.php

```
public function importar(Request $request)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ESPECIALISTA_DC');
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('file', FileType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [ 'label' => 'Guardar',  'attr' => array('onclick' => 'cargando()')])
            ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            ...
        }
        return $this->render('general/importar.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

ImportarArchivo.html.twig

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.file) }}
    {{ form_row(form.save) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/427597/54039) hay un ejemplo para estilizar campos de archivo, no es con Bootstrap pero puede servirte de ejemplo. Para Bootstrap, revisa la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#file-input). Si ninguna de las dos opciones cumple con lo que necesitas, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más detalles como qué es lo que esperas que pase y qué es lo que se está mostrando.

Comment: [Symfony en su documentación](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/bootstrap4.html#file-inputs) habla como se puede hacer esto. Seguramente, en vez de usar `form_row` para el `file`tengas que [dividirlo en partes](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-functions) (`form_label`, `form_widget`, etc)